# Not able to post file using python with POST API?

Tags: python, postman

I am posting data using Postman it's working ok. But when I am converting it's in python it's not able to read my file. It's giving null data in file I don't known what's wrong .

Here is the python code:

```
import requests
url = "http://localhost:63387/api/clientdetail"
payload = "------WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; " \
      "name=\"ip\"\r\n\r\n10.2.3.5\r\n------WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; " \
      "name=\"file\"; filename=\"D:\\data.json\"\r\n" \
      "Content-Type: application/json\r\n\r\n\r\n------WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW--"
headers = {
'content-type': "multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW",
'cache-control': "no-cache",
'Postman-Token': "adcea715-e97c-4374-80b7-30094e0861c3"
}
response = requests.request("POST", url, data=payload, headers=headers)

print(response.text)
```

I am copying this from postman.
here I am passing two parameter string and file so string is working ok but file gives null.

and when I doing this using postman it's giving both correct

so can anyone help me ???

Here is postman HTTP code

```
POST /api/clientdetail HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:63387
cache-control: no-cache
Postman-Token: d614bdb0-eadd-4d29-9132-bc9443176082
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=----
WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="ip"
10.2.3.5
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename="D:\data.json"
------WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW--
```

Comment: it seems you are missing a bracket at the end of row before the last one
`response = requests.request("POST", url, data=payload, headers=headers` **)**

Comment: it also seems your `payload` variable is only storing a string and not a file. How did you come up with this code ? are you following some guide ? if so please share the source so we can check

Comment: Are you sure the method is `POST` and not `PUT`? Which error do you get?

Comment: I am copying this code from postman python request

Comment: @PedroLobito , Ya it's POST method not put.  when I am debugging it in console so there it is giving null data for file

Comment: @reportgunner ,  here in copy paste it missing but in my python code closing bracket is there.

Comment: Well could you edit the question and copy-paste the exact code you have?

Comment: @JJJ, Only closing bracket is missing otherwise it is same code here which I am running.

Answer (score 0):

The only thing that stops you from using urlopen directly on a file object is the fact that the builtin file object lacks a len definition. A simple way is to create a subclass, which provides urlopen with the correct file. I have also modified the Content-Type header in the file below.

```
import os
import urllib2
class EnhancedFile(file):
    def __init__(self, *args, **keyws):
        file.__init__(self, *args, **keyws)

    def __len__(self):
        return int(os.fstat(self.fileno())[6])

theFile = EnhancedFile('a.xml', 'r')
theUrl = "http://example.com/abcde"
theHeaders= {'Content-Type': 'text/xml'}

theRequest = urllib2.Request(theUrl, theFile, theHeaders)

response = urllib2.urlopen(theRequest)

theFile.close()


for line in response:
    print line
```